# Conflicting javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I have seen some questions but non of the answers apply to me.

I have two scripts

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"><script>
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

Depending on which order I place them the code for the other breaks. When I look at the source code I see its because the function names conflict. I need to load both.

Can I somehow make the entire second library load into a separate namespace? How do I go about making all the functions load from both scripts :/

**What I'm trying to do**
I need to call `prettyPrint()` from `run_prettify.js`

what `prettyPrint()` does is insert `<ol>`'s and `<li>`'s and `<span>`'s and into my  tag which contains a chunk of code. Then once those tags are inserting my custom css can style the chunk of code.

Comment: What is the name of that function?

Comment: It depends upon whether the conflicting function name is used internally in both libraries.  If it is not used internally in at least one of the libraries, then it is possible to load the library, assign the conflicting function(s) to other names and then load the other library.  If the conflicting names are used internally in the libraries, then you will have to edit one of the libraries to fix.  So, more details and analysis are required to know the answer.

Comment: Looking at the code I see they both use names like `function a` `function A` and so on. 

I need to call `prettyPrint()` from `run_prettify.js` what it does is insert `ol`'s and `li`'s and `<spans>` and into my `<pre>` tag which contains code. so it essentially styles my code snippet.

Comment: function a and function A should all be private, the exposed names of them should be different, they are called that because they are both minimized

Comment: thanks gabriel i got it all now you are right ofc, it had nothing to do with conflicting function names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at RequireJS http://requirejs.org/. It is a library designed to build javascript modules which are completely self contained and manages dependencies for you as well.

Using RequireJS you could do something like:

```
require(["js/bootstrap.min"], function(bootstrap) {
    //use bootstrap here
});

require(["https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify"], function(run_prettify) {
    //use run_prettify here
});
```